# What is the definition of a "model"?

Tags: neural-networks, machine-learning, models

What is the definition of a "model" in the discussion of a neural network?

I need a canonical definition.

Can you please supply me with a definition along with a reference from any book or research article?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When reading books and articles about machine learning or artificial intelligence in general, one can safely assume that the word "model" is used as an abbreviation for "[Statistical model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statistical_model)". Surprisingly many books skip
the job of providing a definition for it, allegedly cause the authors consider it a sort of primitive concept, i.e. they leave the hot potato there hoping that the readers are already familiar with statistics and data science (special mention in this regard to [Pattern Recognition and Machine Learning](http://users.isr.ist.utl.pt/%7Ewurmd/Livros/school/Bishop%20-%20Pattern%20Recognition%20And%20Machine%20Learning%20-%20Springer%20%202006.pdf) , big classic in which Bishop just use the word from the very beginning without any concern). But in general the closest entity associated with statistical model is just a mathematical function.

Here some references to point that out:

- [Applied predictive Modeling (Max Kuhn, Kjell Johnson, 2013)](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-1-4614-6849-3):

"Predictive modeling: the process of developing a **mathematical tool or model**
that generates an accurate prediction" [page 2, Introduction]

- [An Introduction to Statistical Learning (G. James, D. Witten, T. Hastie, R. Tibshirani, 2021)](https://www.ime.unicamp.br/%7Edias/Intoduction%20to%20Statistical%20Learning.pdf)

"Broadly speaking, supervised statistical learning involves building a **statistical model** for predicting, or estimating, an output based on one or more inputs." [page 1 Introduction]

- [Deep Learning (I. Goodfellow, Y. Bengio, A. Courville, 2016)](https://www.deeplearningbook.org/)

"The quintessential example of a **deep learning model** is the feedforward deep
network, or multilayer perceptron (MLP). A multilayer perceptron is just a
**mathematical function** mapping some set of input values to output values." [page 7 Introduction]

If you're not satisfied and you're looking for a dense, algebraic definition of statistical model, you can check [What is a statistical model?](http://www.stat.uchicago.edu/%7Epmcc/pubs/AOS023.pdf) by Peter McCullagh. I won't try to explain the definition in the answer cause honestly it's really though and it goes beyond my math skills.